# How can I list all the post titles I submitted in a Discord server? (only the titles and not the contents)

Tags: discord

My Discord username is `franckdernoncourt`. I am aware that I can use `from:franckdernoncourt` to see how all the posts I sent in one Discord server. However, it lists both the posts' titles and the posts' contents:

[image]

This makes it inconvenient to quickly scroll through the posts I submitted in a Discord server. I only want to see the post titles, not the post contents. How can I list all the post titles I submitted in a Discord server?